# Android - Animation onClick in image of RecyclerView as Whatsapp

Tags: android, image, animation, android-recyclerview, whatsapp

How I can clicking on an `image of a row of a RecyclerView`, display an image in the center of the screen with an **animation** like `Whatsapp`?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `shared element transition`.

In your `RecycleAdapter` add these line . `android:transitionName="TRANSITION_NAME"`

```
<ImageView
    android:transitionName="TRANSITION_NAME"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/content_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/content_height" />
```

Also , in the next page's `ImageView`also add the same line

Comment: And to display the image in the same activity? I want to show the image on the recyclerview

Comment: As far as i understand there are 2 activity here . One is normal `Activity` and another is `AlertDialouge` as an activity (top on the Recycleview). Or, If you want to do it in a activity then you have to write custom animation to show that way .